# querying locations of structs inside uniform block objects

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

I am trying to setup some structures inside my UBO, but when querying the locations on the struct I added, I get an invalid value.

I modifying this sample to see how it works.

https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/opengl-40-using-uniform-blocks-and-uniform-buffer-objects

so I basically added:

```
struct LightParameters
{
    vec3 pos;
};

layout (std140) uniform BlobSettings
{
  vec4      InnerColor;
  vec4      OuterColor;
  float     RadiusInner;
  float     RadiusOuter;

  LightParameters   lightParam;
};
```

then I tried:

```
// Query for the offsets of each block variable
const GLchar *names[] =
{
    "InnerColor", "OuterColor", "RadiusInner", "RadiusOuter", "pos",
};

glGetUniformIndices(shaderLight.programId, 4+1, names, uniformBlock.loc);
```

where uniformBlock.loc is just an array of locations GLuint[5] but by uniformBlock.loc[4] is invalid after the call, which is just the struct I added.

Can someone point me on the right direction?

Comment: You are using std140 layout. There is absolutely no reason for you to be querying uniform indices; you already know the offsets for the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doing

```
"InnerColor", "OuterColor", "RadiusInner", "RadiusOuter", "lightParam.pos",
```

worked.

Comment: FYI: the [OpenGL Wiki](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Program_Introspection#Interface_block_member_naming) has a page about how all GLSL elements are named. Including the names of interface block members.